# How come julia won't run this code?

Tags: julia

I am in the process of trying to learn a little about using Julia by translating an old example code which solves the time dependent Schrodinger equation. Here is what I have so far:

```
require("setparams.jl")
require("V.jl")
require("InitialRIM.jl")
#require("expevolve.jl")


function doit()

    Nspace, R, Im, x0, width, k0, xmax, xmin, V0, a, dx, dx2, n, dt = setparams()   
R, Im = initialRIm(width,n,k0,dt,xmin)
ProbDen = zeros(Nspace)
ProbDen = R.*R + Im.*Im
plot(ProbDen)
#Imold = Im;
t=0.0
#t, R =evolve!(R,Im,t,V0,width,a,dx,dx2,dt,xmin,n)

println("Done")

end
```

After requiring the above code, I then do using Winston.  Then I attempt to run the code by typing doit().  Nothing appears.

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?  I can provide the innards of setuparame() if needed, as well as initialRIm() but thought at first I'd ask whether my expectations about what should happen are in fault.  Note that if I run setuparams() and initialRIm() in a terminal session, then do the plot(ProbDen), the correct graph appears.

Thanks for your help.

Update:

I have now restarted julia, have done using Winston, and then have done doit() to wit:

julia> using Winston

julia> require("driveSch.jl")

julia> doit()
ERROR: dx not defined
 in initialRIm at /Users/comerduncan/juliaexamples/TDSch/InitialRIM.jl:8
 in doit at /Users/comerduncan/juliaexamples/TDSch/driveSch.jl:11

However, the call to setparams() sets dx along with all the other things. This I see when I run the setparams() interactively.  So I am not understanding what is the problem...

Comment: You should probably do `using Winston` before any code calling `plot` is entered.

Comment: Actually, I just heard from Mike Nolta that using display(plot(ProbDens)) is a better thing to try. Indeed it does work whereas just using plot did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you use `dx` in `initialRIm`, but `dx` is not one of the arguments you pass to it. If you access a variable that is not a parameter nor assigned inside a Julia function, Julia will look for a variable with the same name in the surrounding scopes. When you run

```
Nspace, R, Im, x0, width, k0, xmax, xmin, V0, a, dx, dx2, n, dt = setparams()
```

in the global scope, and you create a global variable `dx` that `initialRIm` could access. When you wrap the calls into a function, you create a local variable `dx` that can not be accessed from `initialRIm`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have now resolved all issues and the code runs just fine...plus I learned some useful things.